# iOS Never reaching DidApplicationFinishLaunching.. never shows view

Tags: iphone, interface-builder, xib

I am confused, I have an iOS app targeted for Iphone

The MainWindow.xib file has its Window and a VIEW that is set up to load from another XIB file

The WINDOW in MainWindow.xib has not outlets connected at all.

This was all working before, and suddenly stopped so I am assuming something in the XIB's is now off (references, delegates, something isn't linked right).

The View has its App Delegate connected to the viewController class for itself.

When the application now launches, it just shows an empty WINDOW, and the DidApplicationFinishLaunching in my AppDelegate Class NEVER gets called.

I assume I have something missing/broken in the associations of the Window and the app delegate or views..

The View is an instance of myViewController and AppDelegate is set to myAppDelegate

Yet no matter how I link things up with delegate outlets etc it just sits there with a blank window mocking me.

I know I screwed up something, since this all worked beautifully up until InterfaceBuilder decided to hork something.

Any Help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you post a picture of your `MainWindow.xib` with the left menu that depicts the objects in the NIB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The View has its App Delegate connected to the viewController class for itself.

Errr this sentence does not mean anything. A view does not have an AppDelegate.

The object that we usually call "the AppDelegate" is the object that we set as the Delegate for the UIApplication singleton object.

When your application starts, the `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method of your AppDelegate is not called by magic: it is called because this object (of type YourAppName_AppDelegate) is set as the delegate of your UIApplication object ; this connection is done in your MainWindow XIB file by connecting the "delegate" IBOutlet of the UIApplication instance to the YourAppName_AppDelegate object.

I guess for your case this connection between the app singleton's delegate outlet and the AppDelegate object implementing `didFinishLaunching` is broken and needs to be redone.

*Note that in the special case of the MainWindow.XIB file, as this XIB is the one automatically opened when your application starts (except if you change this in your Info.plist file), the File's Owner of this XIB is also the UIApplication singleton, so that you can connect either the File's Owner delegate IBOutlet or the UIApplication object delegate in your XIB, as this is the same singleton object.*

Comment: I did get the appDidFinishLaunching to get called, it was indeed missing the delegate link between the main window and the delegate.. however I am still not seeing the View that the main window is suppose to be loading as configured in Interface Builder...

Comment: Can't see your code you tried to post in the previous comment.

Comment: But again, check that all your outlets are connected. E.g. if your code contains [window addSubview:viewcontroller.view] to add your main ViewController's view to the window's view hierarchy, ensure that the outlet from your AppDelegate to your ViewController is connected, as well as the one from your ViewController to its own view. Don't forget to call [window makeKeyAndVisible] too.

Comment: the mainwindow.xib contains a delegate a viewcontroller and the window, the viewcontroller and delegate are assigned to be my classes, and tying the window delegate to my delegate class does get the didFinishLaunching to execute.. what I think is missing is the tie from that window the VIEW CONTROLLER which is set up to load a seperate nib.. I just cant seem to figure out what needs to be linked to what to make this viewcontroller get created and load the xib... the code is as follow in my did finish launching, and the view in the viewcontroller it references is NIL every time.

Comment: [window addSubview:mapViewController.view];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];

Comment: Added link from window to viewcontroller.. that gets it further.. but then die with a bad sig... So I'll keep investigating

Comment: Why don't you use the debugger (or NSLogs) to check the values of the different variables used? That's the first thing to do in such cases. Check that your mapViewController is not nil, neither its view, etc.

Comment: I have done this, it is now dying on the widow addSubview:mapViewController.view  both mapViewController and its View exist at the time of the call, but that call results in a bag sig.

Comment: its an exec bad access which implies something is off, but the view and the controller are right... so I'm still confused.

Comment: I did have something wrong in the connections that started this in IB, but I got that fixed and still had a bad NSLog that I put in for tracing that problem that was leading to the bad access... but the real problem was that I added a LOG call that had

Comment: This was due to an NSLog() call that had the @ inside the ""  NSLog("@ log text") instead of NSLog(@"log text");  This was the root cause of the bad access... Wild, but thankfully its back to working again.

Comment: You probably added a NSLog("xxx") instead of NSLog(@"xxx"), or used a bad formatting placeholder (like %@ with the corresponding parameter being an integer). You probably had a warning about that during compilation; NEVER ignore the warning, especially if your program is already crashing fix all the warning before going further ;)

Comment: So I guess my answer was the good one and your question is solved then?

Comment: Yes, thank you I must have broken, or IB broke the links to the delegate or viewcontroller, but now everything seems to be working again, thank goodness.

Now back to the original problem I was trying to solve when all this started... Why the heck the view rotation isn't functioning properly.